# Reading package lists quits without any explanation

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm trying to do a simple `apt-get install` like

```
sudo apt-get -V install chrome
```

It displays "Reading package lists... 6%" and then abruptly quits so the line now looks like

```
user@server:~$ ists... 6%
```

and nothing has happened.

I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get purge
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

When I do `sudo apt-get update` it seems to work until it hits the package lists, and then it again stops around 6%.

`sudo apt-get upgrade` does the same thing.

I'm not very familiar with Linux so I've tried googling around but I haven't found anything. Does anyone have any suggestions?